# Jitter with notification on Job Search

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

There appears to be a jitter with a notification on the job search page where the notification bounces up and down; it is going up and down at the designated rate but as you can see there is jitter during that process. The portion where the GIF fades is a transition caused by my iPhone; the full animation has jitter from top to bottom and moves through at a steady rate with the jitter occurring throughout.

[image: Compressed GIF]

---

I am using Microsoft Edge running on Windows 10. My computer specs (at least the ones I am aware of) are:

- Brand: Acer
- Model: Republic of Gamers - GL553V
- CPU:

  - Intel i7
  - 16GB RAM
- GPU:

  - NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX
  - 4GB RAM

---

At work it works in Microsoft Edge on Windows 10; I'll update with my home version of Edge this evening, but for comparison:

- Work: Microsoft Edge 40.15063.674.0

  - EdgeHTML 15.15063
- Home: Microsoft Edge 41.16299.15.0

  - EdgeHTML 16.16299

I tested in the latest version of Chrome with no issues; the animation displays nice and smooth, probably just a Microsoft Edge thing.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Unfortunately not, I'm running Microsoft Edge on an Acer ROG running Windows 10 and am definitely getting a jitter. I'll update my post with a semi-accurate depiction with code. I wish I was seeing what you linked! That's really smooth!

Comment: Can you specify [which exact version of Edge](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027011/microsoft-edge-find-out-which-version-you-have) you're observing this with? If this is a browser bug (as I suspect it probably is), it might be only present in certain versions.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen They are definitely different; I'll download Chrome here in a few moments and tell you if it is still occurring there too.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Tested it with Chrome and the animation is smooth like it should be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the animation looks like to me:

[image: Screen capture of job alert animation]

The screen capture was taken on Chrome 71 / Mac, but I see the same thing on Firefox and Safari as well.

FWIW, the Stack Snippet below essentially reproduces the actual CSS used to animate the alert box on the [jobs page](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) (minus the redundant `-webkit-` vendor prefix variants of the same styles):

```css
.test_alert {
    animation-name: jobalert;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes jobalert {
    from {
        transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0)
    }
    to {
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
    }
}
```

```html
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div class="test_alert">THIS IS A TEST</div>
```

Running the snippet above *should* show the text "THIS IS A TEST" slowly floating up and down with a four second period.  If it jitters instead on Edge, then I would definitely call this a browser bug.  (Mind you, even if that's the case, it might still be a good idea to try to figure out some work-around for it.)

---

Ps. Here's the same snippet with the `-webkit-` prefixes included, just in case they make a difference:

```css
.test_alert {
    -webkit-animation-name: jobalert;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-name: jobalert;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite
}

@-webkit-keyframes jobalert {
    from {
        transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0)
    }
    to {
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
    }
}

@keyframes jobalert {
    from {
        transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0)
    }
    to {
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
    }
}
```

```html
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div class="test_alert">THIS IS A TEST</div>
```